# using entity framework 6 commands inside a .net standard library causes a crash

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, .net-core

i converted my `data access class library` (which is a normal library) to a **`.net standard library`**, but now when i want to execute a command like `"update-database"`i get an exception in the console:

```
Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject'
```

i am targeting `net461` in standard library btw.

here is the full message:

```
Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
```

i`m using vs 2015 update3.

Thanks in advance.